# How can I free up disk space in my Ubuntu Hardy Heron install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space, ubuntu-8.04

I'd like to make some room on /dev/sda1 without necessarily having to remove a whole bunch of applications (I've already gone through and deleted all frivolous apps).

This is the state of /dev/sda1 currently:

```
Dir: /
Type: ext3
Total: 9.4GiB
Free: 488.6MiB
Available: 0bytes
Used: 8.9GiB
```

**EDIT** added `du` output from comments below:

```
769068 /var/lib/mysql
351208 /usr/lib
297060 /usr/local/bin/eclipse/plugins
184124 /usr/bin
175924 /usr/lib/openoffice/program
143940 /usr/local/bin/eclipsePHP/plugins
 92520 /boot
 81200 /opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/google_apis-6_r01/images
 79964 /opt
```

That's funny, because the tables in /var/lib/mysql are the reason that I ran out in the first place. But I need them, and room for many more possibly large db's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about log files? You could delete and/or compress them. While you're at it, make sure you have logrotate set up - that will take care of automatically compressing, rotating, and deleting your logs on a regular basis.

Comment: I do have logrotate set up and compression is enabled. I didn't make any custom configurations, though. On top of that, I followed this walkthrough: 

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cleaning-up-all-unnecessary-junk-files-in-ubuntu.html

Even after all of that, /dev/sda1 only has 240MB free. I'd like more! Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, if you've deleted everything you can, then really the only recourse you're left with is adding another hard drive.

Comment: I'm swapping it out for a 250GB drive. Yay! Thanks, all.

Answer (score 4):

First, find out what's using your space...

```
# du -k -x -S / | sort -r -n
```

- `-k` - output in kB instead of blocks
- `-x` - don't check other filesystems mounted in the tree
- `-S` - don't include subdir values

**EDIT** From the disk space report you added it seems you have two disk hogs:

1. MySQL - move the data to a different partition, and either reconfigure MysQL (via `/etc/my.cnf`) or put in a symlink from the old location to the new one
2. Development tools - that's a *lot* of Eclipse plugins, and an Android SDK too...

Comment: xdiskusage is *the* visualization tool for this.

Comment: sure, if you want to go all GUI on me... ;-)

Comment: Some may prefer the visualization of kdirstat or gtkfree.  However xdiskusage (and it's grandpa xdu) allow you to visualize a file containing the output of du.  So then you can do things like ssh server2 "du -k /usr"|xdiskusage

Comment: Here are the first several lines of the output from Alnitak's command:

**************************************************************
769068  /var/lib/mysql
351208  /usr/lib
297060  /usr/local/bin/eclipse/plugins
184124  /usr/bin
175924  /usr/lib/openoffice/program
143940  /usr/local/bin/eclipsePHP/plugins
92520   /boot
81200   /opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/google_apis-6_r01/images
79964   /opt


That's funny, because the tables in /var/lib/mysql are the reason that I ran out in the first place. But I need them, and room for many more possibly large db's.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there's packages that you don't really need taking up a lot of space. Ie open-office. The `debian-goodies` package contains a script called dpigs that will list the top ten disk space offenders. 
Example:

```
~$ dpigs
264088 ubuntu-docs
119940 openoffice.org-core
94652 linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic
93752 linux-image-2.6.28-16-generic
92204 linux-image-2.6.27-11-generic
88180 linux-image-2.6.31-21-generic
86024 inkscape
79672 wine1.2
75348 openjdk-6-jre-headless
74320 linux-headers-2.6.32-22
```

If that's not enough you have to consider the point of running mySQL on a drive of a measly ten gigs. If this is for development testing, consider pruning the data. If it's *production*, consider moving it to it's own server or at least it's own disk. I can buy a terrabyte disk for under a hundred dollars now -- the time spent pruning an install and prioritizing useful software seems like a waste in comparison. Just format it, take mysql offline move everything over from /var/lib/mysql and remount the drive to that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the percentage of usage reserved for privileged processes see: `man tune2fs`. Default is 5% of your disk space. Maybe an option is to reduce it to 2% ?

```
# tune2fs -m2 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: That one seems a bit too risky -- I don't want to hose my system because the OS didn't have room (and I'm not Unix-smart enough to deal with that).

Comment: Your call. I'm always reducing it on larger drives.

Comment: What would you consider a 'larger drive'? Mine?

Comment: Try reducing to 3%. Check how much space you gain. You can always switch back to 5%. This is space reserved for privileged processes when there is no space left on device system has to have disk space for sockets, named pipes, temp files, etc. to operate.

Comment: Also check that `/var/lib/mysql` maybe you have large binary log files ? `sudo du -h /var/lib/mysql/*`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem are binary logs check that [how-to-free-up-var-lib-mysql-virtualbox-vm](https://serverfault.com/questions/51264/how-to-free-up-var-lib-mysql-virtualbox-vm)